# How to copy files to /var/www on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions

I’m trying to copy files to the `/var/www` folder on Ubuntu 10.04. But I think I don’t have the permissions.

How can I do this? Is there some specific permission I should set to this folder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `/var/www` is not owned by your user, you need `sudo` privileges to do so. From a terminal, you could run:

```
sudo cp file_you_want_to_copy /var/www
```

Answer (score 16):

You're missing the basics.
Take a look here: http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-9-Manual/getting-started-guide/s1-navigating-ownership.html

Now if you don't want to read everything:
If you regularly need to edit files in /var/www, you should consider changing the owner/group and permissions on that directory.

If your username is 'user', try this:

```
sudo chown user /var/www
```

OR:

```
sudo chgrp user /var/www
sudo chmod 775 /var/www
```

Now you can copy a file with: `cp file /var/www/`

If you just want to copy 1 file without messing with permissions, use:

```
sudo cp file /var/www/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
gksudo nautilus
```

in the terminal, then navigate to `/var/www` and you can create, copy or delete files.

Answer (score 0):

If gksu is not already installed:

> sudo apt-get install gksu

Then do the following:

> gksu nautilus /var/www/html